# Not able to access the Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have database and webpages related to it are uploaded on server but not able to access the database from server but when run on local machine through VS2010 i was able to access it.
Asked Server Admin also about the problem but they told that everything is fine from server side there is problem in code they are saying.

The following error i'm getting:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid object name 'Login'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Login'.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 20: SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select Password from Login where Username='" + Uname_txt.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
Line 21: con.Open();
Line 22: SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
Line 23: try
Line 24: {
```

Comment: Where is the database that you are connecting to? on your laptop? On the same web server that you are running web code, or on a different server? What does your connection string look like?

Answer (score 1):

If everything is working locally, then problem is definitely in how you've setup connecting to the database on the server.

So, look at connection string in web.config and make sure that it is setup properly (if using Integrated Security make sure appropriate APP POOL is allowed to access database).

Also, make sure Login table is indeed created in the database.

Once you do all that you have lots of things to follow up with:

1. Stop using reserved keywords in SQL expressions (Password, Login, etc) or at least wrap them in brackets like [Password].
2. Try to get in habit of referencing schema when working with tables (dbo.Login instead of just Login)
3. Extract queries like that in Stored procedures so that you are [not vulnerable to SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted the connection String, I suspect, you have not supplied the INITIAL CATALOG in connection string, because of which it is directly connected to Master Database and of course your table not exists in Master.

INITIAL CATALOG =  should be added in your connection string. I hope this will help you.

Note: You can also use DATABASE =  in connection string.